# Scrollable HTML Timeline Item

Tags: google-mirror-api

I want to insert TimelineItem that might have more text than could be fit onto Glass' screen. 
Is it possible to create "scrollable" html like in "View Licenses" on Glass?

Comment: You should specify that you want vertical scrolling if that is the case (I believe so based on your example).  As far as I know the only way to accomplish what you are talking about is by bundling by paging using the timelineItem.htmlPages[] property, which of course is horizontal scrolling.  If horizontal scrolling is acceptable, add a comment and I can post an answer.  Otherwise edit your question to specify vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to display smooth scrolling content like you see on the 'View Licenses' card, but you can insert content that is larger than a single card with paging.

If the contents of your `text` attribute exceeds the capacity of a single card, a 'Read More' menu item is automatically added to your card. Selecting this menu item allows your user to page through the rest of the text.

Alternatively, if you'd like to display html content, you can break the content into pages yourself using the [htmlPages](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#htmlPages) property.

Comment: I think he might be asking if its possible to do vertical scrolling like if you go to settings > device info > view licenses.  I am guessing we don't have access to that functionality, that its special and native, but you could say definitively.